# Do I need to explicity destory an instance of 1 class which is within an instance of a 2nd class in Tcl

Tags: oop, tcl, instance, destroy

let's assume that I have class1, created by oo::class create

```
oo::class create class1 {
   method bar {} {
      class2 create bee
      bee method1
   }
}
```

Now, let's say that I have this code:

```
class1 create po
po bar
po destroy
```

Am I destroying also the instance bee within po, or should I also explicitly destroy po::bee?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try writing a little bit of test code? A quick `puts` in a destructor for `class2` would tell you in an instant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `create` method of `oo::class` prefers to resolve names of objects it is creating with respect to the current namespace (i.e., if they're not absolute names). That means that when you call it inside a method of another object with an unqualified name, the object it creates will be put inside that other object. (You can verify this by examining the result of the `create` method, which is the fully-qualified name of the created object for ordinary classes.) In turn, that means that when the outer object is destroyed, the inner objects will also be destroyed when the outer object's instance namespace is deleted and the commands inside it are killed off.

Let's demonstrate by using some simple classes:

```
oo::class create Inner {
    destructor {
        puts "Hi from an Inner"
    }
}
oo::class create Outer {
    method makeAnInner {} {
        puts [Inner create in]
    }
    destructor {
        puts "Hi from an Outer"
    }
}
Outer create out
out makeAnInner
out destroy
```

That prints something like (the namespace name **will** vary) this:

```
::oo::Obj19::in
Hi from an Outer
Hi from an Inner
```

However, it is often better to call the inner object's `destroy` method more directly, since then any errors that occur in the destructor won't get discarded. (With the other destruction scheme, the current internal API can't safely preserve error reporting for various ugly reasons, especially as that's also a deletion route that is used at times when much more extensive deletion is occurring.)

Answer (score 1):

`bee` is created in the namespace of the instance of `class1`, and when the instance is destroyed the namespace is deleted and `bee` goes too.

So you shouldn't need to destroy it explicitly, but if you deal with instances in other namespaces that you want to go away you can set it up to happen automatically in the destructor:

```
oo::define class1 destructor {bee destroy}
```

If one wants a method to create instances that are *not* destroyed when the creating instance is destroyed, either give the created instance a name in another namespace, e.g. `::bee`, or let the method return the result of `class2 new`, calling it like `set cee [po bar]`. The new instance can be used as `$cee` *method arg...*

Documentation:
[oo::define](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/define.htm),
[oo::object](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/object.htm)